# Cannot resolve Gradle Android dependency

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to include the HoloColorPicker library (or for that matter any other library in my project), however, I cannot seem to get it to download.

The dependency section in my build.gradle file looks like:

> ```
> compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
> compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.+'
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:6.5.+'
> compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.+'
> compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5+'
> wearApp project(':Wearable')
> ```

The error message I get is as follows:

> What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project
>   ':Application'. Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration
>   ':Application:_debugCompile'.
>
> > Could not find any version that matches com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5+.
> >          Searched in the following locations:
> >              file:/Users/Tom/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/larswerkman/HoloColorPicker/maven-metadata.xml
> >              file:/Users/Tom/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/larswerkman/HoloColorPicker/
> >              file:/Users/Tom/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/larswerkman/HoloColorPicker/maven-metadata.xml
> >              file:/Users/Tom/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/larswerkman/HoloColorPicker/
> >          Required by:
> >              watchfaces2.0:Application:unspecified

I cannot seem to figure out why Android Studio is looking for the library under my local path as opposed to pulling the library down from the internet. How can I get past this issue?

Comment: Did you add the library to your project at all? to write the line in dependencies will help just if  the gradle system could find matched files in your project or in repositories. The library you trying to use is not in Maven so you need to add it to your preject.

Comment: Which library should I be adding @yshahak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for complete the picture:

```
dependencies {
    repositories {
         mavenCentral()
    }
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:6.5.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5+'
    wearApp project(':Wearable')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you included Maven in your gradle file?

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:6.5.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5+'
    wearApp project(':Wearable')
}
```

Comment: I added in the second line - maven {url ....} but still it fails on the same error.

Comment: Insert repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    } inside dependecies.

Comment: @yshahak - can you give me a sample on what to include?